# How to get JSON Array from external json file without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, router

I am working on creating the classical car API. Now I'm trying to pull a JSON Array from an external file.
I made a step toward a resolution, however my "solution" will return the full object, instead of the array json. [image: Screenshot from Postman]
This is from the vehicles.js file, found under api/routes/

```
import express from 'express';    
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../resources', 'vehicles.json'));
});
export default router;
```

The app.js looks like this:

```
import express from 'express';      
const app = express();     

import vehiclesRoute from './api/routes/vehicles.js';


app.use('/vehicles', vehiclesRoute);                                  

export default app;
```

Something else I tried was in the lines of:

```
import parsedJSON from './resources/vehicles.json';
var vehiclesJSON = parsedJSON.vehicles;

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    let vehiclesJSONpath = path.join(__dirname, '../resources', 'vehicles.json');
    res.status(200).fetch(vehiclesJSONpath)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
});
```

1. Is there a way I can do the parsing and include it in the response body of the callback?
2. Is there maybe a route I need to configure anew, so that the array can be simply extracted?
   Thanks!

Comment: If you are building an API, you likely want to return plain JSON, not objects (the whole reason JSON was invented was to transfer JavaScript data over the wire). I would think that you'd just send the vehicles.json as a file.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you for the input. I think that's what I am going for and I might just have overcomplicated it.

Answer (score 0):

Will close this. The solution was simple.

```
'use strict';
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('api/resources/vehicles.json');
let vehicles = JSON.parse(rawdata);
```

Then, in order to be able to get it as a response:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json(vehicles);
});
```

Saved by: https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/